# List of algorithms?

Tags: lists, algorithms

I have created the following algorithm command in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\algo}[3]{\refstepcounter{algo}
    {
        \centering
        \framebox[\textwidth]{
        \parbox{0.95\textwidth} {\vspace{\topsep}
        {\bf Algorithm \thealgo : #2}\label{#1}\\
        \vspace*{-\topsep} \mbox{ }\\
        {#3} \vspace{\topsep} }}
    }}
```

How can I create a list of Algorithms like `\listoffigures` or `\listoftables`?

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal example for others to work with. Then we know which document class and packages we have to deal with.

Comment: You can use newfloat to create an algorithm float type (not named algo, already used) and use \captionof{algorithm}{...} to add entries to the list (or add \def\@captype{algorithm} to \algo).